# Sorting a linked list using Quicksort in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, quicksort

I was reading about Quicksort, and most of the codes I found were extremely complicated. So, I decided to make one on my own, wherein I considered the first element as pivot and then calling sort function recursively on the rest of the list. 
I made the following code for Quicksort. It's as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node * next;
};

node * newnode (int x);
void quicksort(node ** begin, node ** end);

int main (void)
{
    int foo,n,i,j,k;
    node * temp;
    node * head = NULL;
    node * tail = NULL;
    cout<<"How many nodes do you want to insert\n";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter data of linked list\n";
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        cin>>foo;
        node * bar;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = newnode(foo);
            tail = head;
        }
        else
        {
            bar = newnode(foo);
            tail->next = bar;
            tail = bar;
        }
    }
    cout<<"The linkedlist that you entered is as follows\n"; // Taking input
    temp = head;
    node * prev = NULL;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<"\t";
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Sorting the linked list now\n"; // Calling sort function
    quicksort(&head,&prev);
    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) // Printing output
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<"\t";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

node * newnode (int x) // for allocating a new node
{
    node * foo = new node;
    foo->data = x;
    foo->next = NULL;
    return foo;
}

void quicksort(node ** begin, node ** end) // actual sort function
{
    if (*begin == *end)
        return;

    node * pivot = *begin;
    node * temp = *begin;
    temp = temp->next; // for pointing to next element

    while (temp != *end)
    {
        if (temp->data < pivot->data)
        {
            node * temp1 = *begin;  // swapping the two nodes if less than pivot
            *begin = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            (*begin)->next = temp1;
        }
        else
            temp = temp->next; else moving to next
    }
    quicksort(begin,&pivot); // calling for remaining elements (first half)
    quicksort(&(pivot->next),end); for second half
}
```

Howeever, when I run this, on input as `5 4 3 2 1`, it sort of goes into an infinite loop. I tried running it through a debugger, but it get's extremely complicated to the extent that I lose my way in between. Can you point out the error where I might be going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You're missing a comment marker before `for second half` at the end of `quicksort()`.  It's likely simpler to convert the list into an array, sort the array, and then rebuild a list from the array than to sort the list itself.  Choosing a pivot of `5` means that your sort is totally skewed; the remaining elements are all less than the pivot, and this repeats each time.  I haven't chased the code through, but are you connecting the two parts of the list correctly after the two parts have been sorted separately?

Comment: Quicksort has O(n^2) performance for a linked list. If you don't have the option of copying the data to an array (and it's difficult to think of any reason), then do a merge sort. I.e. the current problem does not matter, because you have to scratch that code anyway.

Comment: As Alf mentioned, a merge sort would be better, but it should be a bottom up merge sort, versus a top down merge sort, due to the top down overhead of repeatedly scanning a sub-lists to split it into two sub-lists. If this is not homework, I can post example code that uses an array of pointers to nodes, where each array[i] points to a list with 2 to the power i nodes in it, which is a fast method for sorting linked lists.

Comment: If you are still interested I found this online: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quicksort-on-singly-linked-list/. As the title says this is for singly linked lists so the sort time is indefinitely longer as we will always have to start from the beginning of the list but I hope it helps.